# Add image to the canvas but the height and width are not as desired

Tags: javascript, image, fabricjs

I'm try https://jsfiddle.net/natchiketa/xHYjz/
and my function :

```
  function addtesst() {
      var imgURL = 'http://i.imgur.com/8rmMZI3.jpg';
      var pugImg = new Image();
      pugImg.onload = function (img) {
          var pug = new fabric.Image(pugImg, {
              width: 800,
              height: 1000,
              left: 150,
              top: 170,
              scaleX: 0.41,
              scaleY: 0.42
          });
          canvas.add(pug);
      };
      pugImg.src = imgURL;
  }
```

and the result:

[image]

```js
var imgURL = 'http://i.imgur.com/8rmMZI3.jpg';

var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');

var pugImg = new Image();
pugImg.onload = function (img) {    
    var pug = new fabric.Image(pugImg, {
        angle: 45,
        width: 500,
        height: 500,
        left: 50,
        top: 70,
        scaleX: .25,
        scaleY: .25
    });
    canvas.add(pug);
};
pugImg.src = imgURL;
```

```css
#canvas {
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px 1px black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.1.0/fabric.all.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas" width="640" height="480"></canvas>
```

As you can see my photo is not full.
Please help me find the problem.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The `width` and `height` properties aren't actually meant to be used by that. They're for setting how many pixels of the original image should be shown. Values larger than the original image dimension mean a larger container, and smaller values result in cropping.

Instead of setting the width, height, scaleX, and scaleY values directly, use these two methods to set your image size:

```
image.scaleToWidth(desiredWidth);
```

or

```
image.scaleToHeight(desiredWidth);
```

If you have specific dimensions in mind and you don't mind your image being stretched, you can also do this:

```
image.set({
  'scaleX': desiredWidth / image.width,
  'scaleY': desiredHeight / image.height
});
```

Comment: Thank you very munch  . It's working but when i used scaleToWidth then scaleToHeight not working . How do they work together?

Comment: you're meant to use one or the other. When you use scaleToWidth, the image's height will change to the correct height for that aspect ratio, and vice versa with scaleToHeight

Comment: I want to use both. Because my purpose is to redraw the image with given length and width. Looking forward to hearing from u

Comment: You won't need to use both to get the size you want. Just use one of them to set the correct `scaleX` and `scaleY` values. Then just adjust the `height` or `width` value as needed.

Comment: Thank you for patiently answering my question. I tried following your answer. It is correct , but what I mean is i have scaleX and scaleY . After adding the image to the canvas ( used scaleToHeight and that's correct) but the width will overflow with the image width. I want the image to always be drawn in the given scaleX and Y , accepting the image with distortion.

Comment: If you don't mind the image stretching, you can do something like this. img.set('scaleX', desiredWidth / img.width)

Comment: Thank you Melchiar very much, that's what I was looking for. it worked